# User not receive message in Outlook when MailItem.Sender changed

Tags: outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

I have mailbox "user1@somemail.com" and I manually changed MailItem.Sender field to "user2@somemail.com" and sent it to "user3@somemail.com". I discovered strange situation that i see email in "SentItems" folder in "user1@somemail.com" but "user3@somemail.com" not receive this message. I checked logs in Exchange server and i donæt see any error messages. Just for prof i did the same but not change MailItem.Sender property but used SentOnBehalf standart functionality. And "user3@somemail.com" receive it so issue not in permission. Just for check i used OutlookSpy and compare two emails(one email that i sent using SentOnBehalf standart functionality and outher email where i changed MailItem.Sender). You can see diferrences following. Can somebody say me where is my fault and why user not receive email when i change MailItem.Sender:

[image: Differences between two mails]

[image: Differences between two mails]

Answer (score 1):

The Sender property is not meant to take a string value.  You need to set it to an AddressEntry object for a user that has permissions to send from any of the loaded accounts in the current Outlook profile.

See MailItem.Sender Property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869056(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I don't use a string i use AddressEntry for that but actually user that i use not in my Outlook profile. I use following code: `mail.Recipients.Add(mail.SentOnBehalfOfName);
mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
var adressEntry = mail.Recipients[mail.Recipients.Count].AddressEntry;
mail.Recipients.Remove(mail.Recipients.Count);
mail.Sender = adressEntry;`

Comment: And actually a long story of using it because i can't just change SentOnBahalf property in ItemSend event because i think it's little bit late to change it. I can change it in ItemSend event but it just do nothing. And my requerement is popup some form after user click on send button and change mail sender here like you can do it in Outlook by changing SentOnBehalf